# How to correctly alias a base class member in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I wrote an `Edge` class like this:

```cpp
struct Edge : public ::std::pair<int, int>
{
  using ::std::pair<int, int>::pair;
  int &src = first;
  int &dst = second;
};

namespace std
{
  template <>
  struct hash<Edge>
  {
    std::size_t operator()(Edge const &x) const noexcept
    {
      return (x.src << 16) | x.dst;
    }
  };
}
```

So I can use `src`/`dst` to substitute `first`/`second`.

However, I found things go wrong when I use `std::unordered_set`.

```cpp
Edge e(1, 2);
print_edge_debug_info(e);
using _set_t = std::unordered_set<Edge>;
_set_t s;
s.insert(e);
for(auto &&_e : s) {
  print_edge_debug_info(_e);
}
/*
output:
 (1, 2) [ 2,0x7ffca1c08724]  [ 2,0x7ffca1c08724] 
 (1, 2) [ 2,0x2bb80fc]  [ 2,0x7ffca1c08724]
*/
```

`print_edge_debug_info`:

```cpp
inline void print_edge_debug_info(Edge const &edge)
{
  std::cout << edge
            << " "
            << "[ " << edge.second << "," << &edge.second << "] "
            << " "
            << "[ " << edge.dst << "," << &edge.dst << "] "
            << std::endl;
}
```

The `dst` and `second` have the same address after the first `Edge` object being constructed. But If I put this `Edge` object into a `std::unordered_set` and fetch it from the set, the addresses of the result's `dst` and `second` are different.

Besides, the new `second` and the old `second` have different address. But the new `dst` and the old `dst` have the same address. Which means the new `dst` is the alias of the old `second`, not the alias of the new `second`.

It seems strange for me. I don't understand why this happened.

Is my way to make member aliases wrong? What's the correct way?

Comment: Reference members are not plain aliases. They are proper members that have to be accounted for in copying, assigning or moving. Adding references to the mix makes [the rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violations stand out more, which I suspect is the case here. Why not just use member function accessors instead? It will save you a whole lot of headaches.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica In fact, I have already change them to getter/setters yesterday. I am just curious about what happened with my code. So I write a simple version of my old code (i.e. the above code) and study it.

Comment: Why inherit from `std::pair`? As far as I can see, writing `struct Edge {int src; int dst;};` would do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The following, smaller example demonstrates the problem with the shown approach.

```
Edge a{1, 2};

// ...

Edge b=a;
```

`a`'s `src` and `dst` references refer to `a.first`, and `a.second`, as expected.

`b`'s `src` and `dst` references ...also refer to `a.first` and `a.second`, for the simple reason that there is no valid reason for them to be anything else, here. That's what you're observing with your set.

A better idea that avoids unexpected surprises is to simply avoid using references in the first place:

```
int &src()
{
    return first;
}

int src() const
{
    return first;
}
```

(and the same with `second`). This also has the advantage of not requiring `Edge` to take up twice the memory, just to carry the references around. It is unlikely that a C++ compiler, even with a proper `=` will figure out how to optimize them out.

There are very good reasons for references to exist in C++ but they are not meant to be used to create aliases to class members. That's not what their semantics are designed for.